# filter notification's delete

Tags: python, django, notifications

My notification system, has the option "Delete", is like "make as read", then i wish when the user do the action "read", just disapare from his notifications and no in general user who has this notification.

**Model.py**

```
class Notificaciones(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(MiUsuario)
    Tipo_de_notificaciones = ( (1,'Ofertas'),(2,'Error'),(3,'Informacion'))
    Tipo = models.IntegerField('Tipo de notificacion',choices=Tipo_de_notificaciones, default=3,)
    titulo = models.CharField("Nombre de la notifiacion",max_length=50)
    mensaje = models.TextField("Descripcion de la notificacion")
    imagen = models.ImageField("Imagen de la notificacion",upload_to="notificaciones")
    Fecha_Caducidad_notificacion = models.DateField("Fecha de caducidad",auto_now=False,auto_now_add=False)
    Estado = models.BooleanField("Estado de la notificacion", default=False)
```

and my views where the login to delete happend

**views.py**

```
def delete_notificaciones(request, notificaciones_id):
    notifi = Notificaciones.objects.get(id=notificaciones_id)
    notifi = Notificaciones.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)
    notifi.Estado = True
    for notifi in notifi:
        notifi.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

**URL.py**

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<notificaciones_id>\d+)/$', 'app.views.delete_notificaciones', name='Vulpini.co'),
```

why no filter the user and make the notification like read.

Answer (score 0):

```
notifi = Notificaciones.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)
```

`user` field in your model is an object, not a field, so you should filter like this:

```
notifi = Notificaciones.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

I think you should change a little bit your view. I guess that you're doing a soft delete by changing `Estado` to `True`.

The code below will mark all user's notifications as read:

```
def delete_notificaciones(request, notificaciones_id):
    notifi = Notificaciones.objects.get(id=notificaciones_id)  # I don't know why you get this object
    notifi = Notificaciones.objects.filter(user=request.user)  # Here you get a QuerySet, not an object

    # use update instead of iterate over the QuerySet

    notifi.update(Estado=True)

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

If you want to mark as read only the current passed by id notification, you should do simething similar to:

```
def delete_notificaciones(request, notificaciones_id):
    notifi = Notificaciones.objects.get(pk=notificaciones_id, user=request.user)
    notifi.Estado = True
    notifi.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: I did but just reload the page and no delete the notification from the user

Comment: i use the get `ID` because so i filter the notification the user going to `make as read`, but now when i implement your code all the notifications `make as read`, let me update the code and show the **url.py**, where delete the notification

Comment: i tried that before post, and when i do chage the Status to all users and no the user make as read

Comment: Please be specific about what you want to do in your view, I understand you want mark as read, but what does it mean? what should be change to be read?

Comment: yes i want mark as read, the idea is a notification system like Google, can to see when i click on the close the notification disapared, that is like a mark as read to me.

Comment: I am sure the second code I posted, your notification is being changed, so that's marked as read, what is the problem?

Comment: yes, that Works but then all user's notifications mark as read, but i need just mark the user made the action, mark as read

Comment: @alfredohb.q Really? it's a get() it should return only one object, but anyway I updated my answer again, the second code block